# Is it possible to have a scrolling listview inside a popup using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, popup

I want to create something like the image on the right in this picture:

http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/4.19_Walmart1.jpg

Basically I want the popup to fill my screen, but not extend downwards when the listview is too big. It should enable the user to scroll the list within the popup. Currently I can't find a solution to limit the height of the popup. I'm using the latest jQuery Mobile.

Any suggestions are more than welcome!

Regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 2):

It can be done like that, take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/caQY5/) example.

In this example you have 1 page as main content and second page which will serve as a content for the dialog box.

This java script will show second page as a dialog box:

```
$('#test').bind('click', function(e) {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#test-dialog", {transition: "none", role: "dialog"} );
});
```

One more thing, I forgot you wanted a listview and I have used controlgroup, you can still replace one with another to achieve needed functionality. One more thing, unlike your example jQM dont have opacity/transparency effect around dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've updated your fiddle to show my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yjUdm/1/ . I don't want the items to go off the screen, they need to be contained within the dialog and allow for scrolling through them. Can you help me achieve this?

Comment: Yes with this plugin https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview but I dont have much experience with it, I used it only once.